# Heap memory analysis

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory

I have a process which runs in `Solaris` continuously.
The heap memory usage of the process keeps on increasing as time goes and when it exceeds 4Gb, process core dumps.

I tried to run the process with `Purify`, but could not find any code which really leaks memory.

Is there any way to analyze which code is responsible for the increased heap memory usage?
The heap memory usage of the process is increasing by 4Mb or 8Mb every 15 minutes and it never decreases.

I have used `pmap` command to check the process heap memory usage.

Comment: It might be that you technically don't leak the memory, but actually keep some pointer to it, somewhere. Purify will then think it is ok.

Comment: @BoPersson Are you saying about dangling pointers?

Comment: No, they are not dangling if you forget to delete some of them. Like building a long list, and add things but some are never deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I would log to a file all the calls to `new` and `delete` with the location that they are called to find out whene the `new` functions are called without a correcsponding `delete` is called. Perhaps you have circular loops within the heap.

Comment: @cppcoder - When one object points to another object and that objec teither directly or indirectly points back to the first object.